# Left recursive arithmetic when creating parser with Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, recursion, functional-programming, monads

I am trying to create a parser in Haskell using the `readP` [library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html) that is left associative in it's (arithmetic) output. In the simplified code below I obviously get either an infinite loop in case `pOp` is called in the left part of an expression (see outcommented code) or I get a right associative output such as `2+(4+(6+8))` the equivalent of:

```
ghci> parseString "2+4+6+8"
[(Oper Plus (Const (IntVal 2)) (Oper Plus (Const (IntVal 4)) (Oper Plus (Const (IntVal 6)) (Const (IntVal 8)))),"")]
```

MVE:

```
import Data.Char

import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP
--import Text.Parser.Char
import Control.Applicative ((<|>))


type Parser a = ReadP a 

data Value =
  IntVal Int
  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

data Exp =
    Const Value
  | Oper Op Exp Exp
  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

data Op = Plus
  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

space :: Parser Char
space = satisfy isSpace


spaces :: Parser String 
spaces = many space


space1 :: Parser String
space1 = many1 space

symbol :: String -> Parser String
symbol = token . string

token :: Parser a -> Parser a
token combinator = (do spaces
                       combinator)


parseString input = readP_to_S (do                         
                        e <- pExpr 
                        token eof
                        return e) input


pExpr :: Parser Exp 
pExpr = 
    (do
            pv <- pOp
            return pv)
        <|>
    (do         
        pv <- numConst 
        skipSpaces       
        return pv) 


numConst :: Parser Exp
numConst = 
        (do  
            skipSpaces
            y <- munch isDigit            
            return (Const (IntVal (read y)))
        )

pOp :: Parser Exp 
pOp = (do 
        e1 <- numConst -- pExpr 
        skipSpaces          
        op <- symbol "+"                           
        e2 <- pExpr
        pv <- pOper op e1 e2 --
        return pv)
        

pOper :: String -> Exp -> Exp -> Parser Exp 
pOper "+" exp1 exp2 = (do return (Oper Plus exp1 exp2))
```

I have tried different strategies such as using `look` from the above mentioned documentation to look ahead with the intention to then take the string returned and apply a parenthesis around it using `"("++ e ++ ")"` where `e` is the expression, and then have a seperat function deal with that call  on the parenthesized expression in order to avoid a loop. But this isn't a viable solution since you can't use the readP library functions on the resulting value of `look` the same way you would use it on the original input (of `look`).

Any ideas how to solve this problem. I don't know if I am jsut getting the grammer (BNF) stated incorrectly to begin with and that I am really just approaching the problem from the wrong angle. But I don't think so.

Comment: It looks like you need to refactor your grammar. You should think of `a+b+c` as something that starts with `a` and then continues with `+b` and then `+c`. So, an expression is a "term" followed by zero or more "+term". A term is either a literal or a parenthesized expression. To add multiplication (with higher precedence) you'll need to add more productions to "term". You can't have a generic "op" case unless all such cases have the same precedence. I think the key term here is "LL(1) grammar", you can try searching for that to see some grammar examples.

Comment: @chi what is the idea and usage of `look` then?

Comment: `look` is not something that is commonly used in parsing. Textbook LL(1) or LL(k) parsing only inspects the next (next k) input tokens, while `look` allows one to inspect much further. I never used it, but I guess it might come handy in a few rare cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [`chainl1 :: ReadP a -> ReadP (a -> a -> a) -> ReadP a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html#v:chainl1). Most parser combinator libraries will have `chainl` and `chainr` families of functions, for parsing operators in a left- or right-associative way. You could apply it like:

```
pExpr = chainl1 numConst (Oper Plus <$ symbol "+")
```

The implementation of `chainl1` is exactly what chi recommends in a comment and what your answer implements: it parses `p`, then parses any number of `op`+`p` pairs.

This addresses your current issue, but once you add a second operator you'll have some decisions to make about precedence. If you want `+` and `*` to have the same precedence (unusual), you can just use this approach but enrich the separator parser. If you want `*` to have higher precedence, you'll need to break `pExpr` up into multiple parsers: instead of `Expr`, parse a `Sum` of `Product`s, stuff like that. Then you'll need one `chainl1` to parse the terms of a `Sum`, where each term is itself parsed with `chainl1` to produce a `Product`.

Comment: What does `<$` do in this expression?  I noted in my own answer below that the result isn't really recursive. I have now posted another question about some specifications about the `chanl1` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74850177/using-chainl1-correctly-with-infix-in-haskell

Comment: `x <$ y` is just a more modern way to write `y >> return x`. I don't really understand what you mean about not being recursive. Yes, `chainl1` lets you outsource the recursion to the parser library. But it's still recursive, and produces a recursive data structure as a result.

Comment: Sorry I meant left-associative, not recursive. It is recursive. And that had to do with my own 'answer' not the `chainl1`.

Answer (score 0):

Due to above comment I was now able to come up with a solution based on a change in grammar.

```
parseString input = readP_to_S (do                         
                        e <- pExpr 
                        token eof
                        return e) input


pExpr :: Parser Exp 
pExpr = 
    (do
        pv <- numConst
        pv2 <- pOpRight pv               
        return pv2
        )
        <|>
    (do         
        pv <- numConst 
        skipSpaces       
        return pv)
      
   
numConst :: Parser Exp
numConst = 
        (do  
            skipSpaces
            y <- munch isDigit            
            return (Const (IntVal (read y)))
        )

pOpRight :: Exp -> Parser Exp 
pOpRight e1 = (do                 
        op <- symbol "+"
        skipSpaces
        e2 <- pExpr        
        pv <- pOper op e1 e2 --
        return pv)

pOper :: String -> Exp -> Exp -> Parser Exp 
pOper "+" exp1 exp2 = (do return (Oper Plus exp1 exp2))
```

Comment: Note that [`ReadP` is not an efficient parser library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html#t:ReadS), because it uses backtracking to consider all possible parses. Your implementation of `pExpr` only works because of this backtracking. I don't think you have any *nested* backtracking yet, so the inefficiencies won't add up to much for now. But if speed is a concern at all (you will be parsing non-toy inputs) it would be better to write an unambiguous parser instead.